# How to transitionWithView and have original view higher on hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

Basically I have a UIView that is a Calendar Month View and then I have a Year view with buttons of all the months in a year. My intended animation is that when a monthBar button is tapped, the current monthView will shrink and go to the intended frame of the current month on the Year View. I have this correct animation, but the original view that is front, the currentMonthView, is behind the YearView instead of being on top. Here is what I have right now:

```
- (IBAction)monthBarTapped:(id)sender
{
    if (_monthBarImageView.highlighted) {
        [self _animateOutYearCalendar:0];
        return;
    }
    _calendarYear = [_calendarStartDate year];

    [self _refreshYearCalendar];

    // animate in year calendar
    _yearCalendarView.hidden = NO;
    [_yearCalendarView setFrameHeight:0];
    self.curMonthView.monthLabel.hidden = YES;

    _curMonthView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [self bringSubviewToFront: _curMonthView];
        _curMonthView.frame = _curMonthButtonFrame;
        _curMonthView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(yearCalendarAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    }];
//    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateYearCalendarIn" context:nil];
//    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];  // kAnimation_AnimateInDuration];
//    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
//    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector (yearCalendarAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];
//
    [_yearCalendarView setFrameHeight:_yearFlyoutHeight];
//
//    [UIView commitAnimations];  // start animation
    _monthBarImageView.highlighted = YES;
    [self _refreshMonthButton:NO];
}
```

TLDR: The frame shrinks to the correct position, but the `_curMonthView` is behind the `yearCalendarView` during the animation in terms of display hierarchy. I want to bring that view to be in front of the `yearCalendarView` and then eventually disappear from view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `insertSubview` method, this should work.